Clear cache but NOT the cookies in mobile Safari
How does one only clear the cache in mobile Safari while leaving the cookies untouched? The only method I know clears both.

Maybe try some third-party apps like PhoneClean or something similar, because there is no built-in way in Safari to clear only the cache without cookies. Or at Safari Settings go to Advanced - Website Data and individually delete website data, you can clear some cache without affecting all cookies.

Is Phone Clean an iOS app? If so, how would it be able to clear another app's data?
